# A stored procedure works only when I restart the SQL Server Database Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

In one my company's internal projects built on C#, ASP.Net, SQL server 2005 and Windows Server 2008, the login stored procedure just takes infinite amount of time when some one tries to login. But when I restart the database server, the problem is fixed. This happens everyday. This might not be database load problem as other stored procedures just work fine. Also if I pull out the query inside the stored procedure, I get the results in proper time. In the stored procedure apart from fetching data there is an if condition which restricts users to some IPs only.

I don't know what the problem is. Can some one please help me in figuring out the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_user]          
@username varchar(50), @pwd varchar(50), @passcode varchar(50), @ipaddress varchar(15)          
AS          
BEGIN          
 IF(@ipaddress = 'aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa' OR @ipaddress = 'aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa' OR @ipaddress = 'aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa')          
 BEGIN          
  IF EXISTS(select up_id from tbl_user_profile (nolock) WHERE up_status='Y')          
  BEGIN          
   DECLARE @ri_date_time varchar(20)          
   SET @ri_date_time=convert(varchar(50),getdate(),120)          
   DECLARE @user_exists as int          
   Set @user_exists = 0          
   Set @user_exists = (Select count(*) from tbl_recent_items (nolock) where ri_user_name=@username)          
   IF @user_exists = 0          
   BEGIN          
    BEGIN TRAN          
     INSERT INTO tbl_recent_items (ri_user_name, ri_access_date_time) values (@username, @ri_date_time+'|'+@ipaddress+'^')          
     IF @@error=0 COMMIT TRAN ELSE ROLLBACK TRAN          
   END          
   ELSE          
   BEGIN          
    DECLARE @datetext varchar(max)          
    SET @datetext = (select isnull(ri_access_date_time,'') from tbl_recent_items(nolock) where  ri_user_name=@username)          
    SET @datetext=@ri_date_time+'|'+@ipaddress+'^'+@datetext          
    BEGIN TRAN          
     UPDATE tbl_recent_items Set ri_access_date_time=@datetext where ri_user_name = @username          
     IF @@error=0 COMMIT TRAN ELSE ROLLBACK TRAN          
   END          
  END          
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(4),up_id) as up_id,LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(up_user_name,''))) as u_user_name,           
  ISNULL(up_password,'') as u_user_password,isnull(up_first_name,'') as up_first_name,           
  ISNULL(up_middle_name,'') as up_middle_name, isnull(up_last_name,'') as up_last_name,           
  ISNULL(up_branch_id,'') as up_branch_id, isnull(b_branch_id,'') as b_branch_id,          
  ISNULL(b_branch_name,'') as b_branch_name,isnull(up_mobile_phone,'') as up_mobile_phone,          
  --ISNULL(up_pager_phone,'') as up_pager_phone,  
  isnull(up_email,'') as up_email,          
  ISNULL(up_status,'') as u_status,   
  --isnull(up_job_posting_phone,'') as up_job_posting_phone,          
--  ISNULL(up_level,'') as up_level, 
    isnull(up_trainee,'0') as up_trainee,          
  ISNULL(up_senior,'0') as up_senior, isnull(up_team_lead,'0') as up_team_lead, isnull(up_ist,'0')as up_ist, up_hyd_branch,    
  convert(varchar(10),up_password_date,102)as up_password_date    
  FROM tbl_user_profile (nolock)           
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_branches (nolock) on up_branch_id = b_id where           
  up_user_name = @username and up_password =@pwd          
 END          
 IF EXISTS(select up_id from tbl_user_profile (nolock) WHERE up_user_name = @username and up_password = @pwd and up_passcode = @passcode and up_status='Y')          
 BEGIN          
  IF EXISTS(select up_id from tbl_user_profile (nolock) WHERE up_status='Y')          
  BEGIN          
   DECLARE @ri_date_time1 varchar(20)          
   SET @ri_date_time1=convert(varchar(50),getdate(),120)          
   DECLARE @user_exists1 as int          
   Set @user_exists1 = 0          
   Set @user_exists1 = (Select count(*) from tbl_recent_items (nolock) where ri_user_name=@username)          
   IF @user_exists1 = 0          
   BEGIN          
    BEGIN TRAN          
     INSERT INTO tbl_recent_items (ri_user_name, ri_access_date_time) values (@username, @ri_date_time1+'|'+@ipaddress+'^')          
     IF @@error=0 COMMIT TRAN ELSE ROLLBACK TRAN          
   END          
   ELSE          
   BEGIN          
    DECLARE @datetext1 varchar(max)          
    SET @datetext1 = (select isnull(ri_access_date_time,'') from tbl_recent_items(nolock) where  ri_user_name=@username)          
    SET @datetext1=@ri_date_time1+'|'+@ipaddress+'^'+@datetext1          
    BEGIN TRAN          
     UPDATE tbl_recent_items Set ri_access_date_time=@datetext1 where ri_user_name = @username          
     IF @@error=0 COMMIT TRAN ELSE ROLLBACK TRAN          
   END          
  END          
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(4),up_id) as up_id,LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(up_user_name,''))) as u_user_name,           
  ISNULL(up_password,'') as u_user_password,isnull(up_first_name,'') as up_first_name,           
  ISNULL(up_middle_name,'') as up_middle_name, isnull(up_last_name,'') as up_last_name,           
  ISNULL(up_branch_id,'') as up_branch_id, isnull(b_branch_id,'') as b_branch_id,          
  ISNULL(b_branch_name,'') as b_branch_name,isnull(up_mobile_phone,'') as up_mobile_phone,          
  --ISNULL(up_pager_phone,'') as up_pager_phone,  
  isnull(up_email,'') as up_email,          
  ISNULL(up_status,'') as u_status,  
   --isnull(up_job_posting_phone,'') as up_job_posting_phone,          
--  ISNULL(up_level,'') as up_level, 
 isnull(up_trainee,'0') as up_trainee,          
  ISNULL(up_senior,'0') as up_senior, isnull(up_team_lead,'0') as up_team_lead,isnull(up_ist,'0')as up_ist, up_hyd_branch,    
  convert(varchar(10),up_password_date,102)as up_password_date    
  FROM tbl_user_profile (nolock)           
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_branches (nolock) on up_branch_id = b_id where           
  up_user_name = @username and up_password =@pwd          
 END          
END
```

Comment: Are there any transactions involved? This can happen when you forget to close one

Comment: I would look at parameter sniffing just as a wild guess. But really we can only give wild guesses without seeing the proc itself.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're getting a bad execution plan cached for that procedure. Hard to say without seeing the code, but [parameter sniffing](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/database-administration/pros-cons-parameter-sniffing-140598) could be an issue. One possible work around could be to use the WITH RECOMPILE option. This will force the stored procedure to recompile and produce a new execution plan every time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourLoginProc
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
...
```

Comment: Isnt the plan created when the procedure is first executed and then kept, thus outlasting a DB restart?

Comment: @Filip The procedure cache exists only in memory. Restarting SQL Server clears that cache.

Comment: But if the procedure cache is getting full, then other procedures should also slow down right. The problem seems to occur with this procedure only.

Comment: @user434509: The problem is not that the cache is full. The problem is that the execution plan stored in the cache for this specific procedure is not appropriate for these particular calls to your procedure.